# Solr IS IN search possible?

Tags: solr

I know this is hard (maybe impossible) to do in RDB like MySQL. I wonder if it is possible to do it with Solr.
This is my task:

I have a Solr index with a field called `parts`. It contains up to 5 random characters like this:

```
12
123
22ac
...
2a
2b
ccc2
1122a
xx12
yy
```

I need the documents returned if all the elements in the `parts` field are in the search term.

For example, if the search term is `21ba`, then `12`, `2a`,`2b`, `1122a` should be returned because all their letters are in the search term.
How to do this in Solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index the parts-terms directly in a `StrField`. When issuing a query, use a Solr regexp matching 1 or more of the query characters: If the search term is `21ba`, the query will be `parts:/[21ba]+/`.

Comment: .. and for those of us who didn't know, all regex-es are anchored by default in Solr. :-) (so ^ and $ are automagically added).

Answer (score 1):

ok,although it isn't proper , but can indeed be achieved , you can use Ngram Analyzer to split every keyword. a example follow below:

```
 <analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="2" />
 </analyzer>
```

it's detail document in [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers) .